# format string to another string format javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach, format

I have the following function:

```
export const getFormatValue = (raw, value) => {
  let maskIndex = 0;
  let formattedValue = '';

  raw.split('').forEach(char => {
    if (value.length > maskIndex && value[maskIndex] === ' ') {
      formattedValue += ' ';
      maskIndex += 1;
    }
    formattedValue += char;
    maskIndex += 1;
  });

  return formattedValue;
};
```

It fails the following test cases

```
Expected: "A   BB   CCC"
Received: "A B BC C C"


> 11 |     expect(getFormatValue('ABBCCC', 'A   AA   AAA')).toBe('A   BB   CCC');
```

My code works for simple cases such as:

```
expect(getFormatValue('23', '0 0000 0000 0000')).toBe('2 3');
```

But soon as the "mask" pattern gets more complicated it fails.

The "mask" value is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the string to be formatted, and then you can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` and check the char in the pattern.

```js
function getFormatValue(str, pattern) {
  const reversed = str.split("").reverse();
  return pattern.split("").reduce((a, c) => [...a, c === " " ? c : reversed.pop()], []).join("");
}

console.log(getFormatValue('ABBCCC', 'A   AA   AAA'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this:

```
export const getFormatValue = (raw, value) => {
   raw = raw.split('');
   return value.replace(/[^\s]/g, () => {
      return raw.shift() || '';
   });
}
```